# Are symbols scoped to the class they're declared in?

Tags: ruby

I've been learning about symbols, and there's one aspect I have a question on that I cannot find an answer to anywhere. It seems relatively common to create a symbol for an accessor on a class:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end

person = Person.new
person.name = "Dennis"
person.name # => "Dennis"
```

Since symbols can only be declared and written to once, does that mean nowhere else in this program can `:name` be created as a symbol? Or is it scoped to the `Person` class, which would allow it to be created elsewhere in other contexts?

Comment: `attr_accessor :name` creates an accessor, it doesn't create a symbol.

Comment: @Stefan : I understood the OP in the way, that its **appearance** (here: **passing** the symbol to the method `attr_accessor`) creates it, and this may indeed be true, since a symbol is "created" by Ruby the first time the compiler encounters it. Hence, unless the compiler has already seen it earlier, the symbol `:name` is indeed created. We could of course argue that _creating **as** a symbol_ does not make much sense. A symbol is not created **as** something, the compiler just notices its existence and if it does not exist yet, creates it.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, your right. If this is the first occurrence of `:name` it would indeed create the symbol. But it doesn't necessarily create a new symbol every time. So thinking of "this creates a symbol" seems misleading to me.

Comment: @Stefan : Get your point! In addition, I just noticed that the title of this post is confusing, in that it mentiones the idea of **declaring** a symbol. A symbol can not be _declared_. I think the OP should write more clearly what he wants to know here.

Comment: What I'm specifically wondering here is if there's that class of `Person` with `attr_accessor :name`, and I create another class of say `Car` that also has `attr_accessor :name`, are each of those symbols distinct and able to have different values because they are in different classes? I apologize if my vocabulary on this isn't completely correct. I'm new to Ruby from another language so some of the concepts (like symbols) are new.

Comment: @Drew `attr_accessor :name` is a _method call_, i.e. `attr_accessor(:name)` with `:name` being the argument. It's a helper to create a so-called getter and setter with the same name as the argument, e.g. `Person#name` and `Person#name=`. Likewise, you can get `Car#name` and `Car#name=`. And even though these methods have the same name, they are scoped by their class. The argument `:name` however is just that: a symbol used as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

`Symbol`s aren't "declared", and they don't have a scope. They just *are*. When you assign the `Integer` `1` to a variable, this does not mean that you aren't allowed to use the `Integer` `1` anywhere else in your program. `Symbol`s are just like numbers. In fact, `Symbol`s are almost exactly like numbers, much more so than they are like `String`s.

Also, `Symbol`s can't be "written to". They are *immutable*, again very much like numbers: you can't "write to" the number `1` and change it into the number two, so that `1 + 1` equals `4`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the terminology straight. In the case of a class of `Person` with `attr_accessor :name`, and I create another class of say `Car` that also has `attr_accessor :name`, are each of those symbols distinct and able to have different values because they are in different classes?

Answer (score 2):

A symbol is global. Every `:name` has the same object id. This is like numbers: Every number `4711` is the same object. You can verify this in irb by doint a

```
:name.object_id == :name.dup.object_id
```

which will return *true*.

Like everyone can use the number 4711, everyone can use the symbol `:name`. If you want to have unique objects, use a String, where you can control duplication

```
v = 'name'
w = v.dup # different object
```